# django login on index page

Tags: python, django, django-login

I'm trying to implement a login system where the user never leaves the front page. So far I've got the following:

The form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next|escape }}" />
</form>
```

The view:

```
def login_user(request):
    state = "Please log in below..."
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."

    return render_to_response('index.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})
```

When I submit a form with a known user, I get the error:

CSRF token missing or incorrect.

What am I doing wrong? I've got the token in the form.

Answer (score 1):

The example code you posted uses render_to_response without context_instance.

Use [django.contrib.shortcuts.render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead of render_to_response, it *all* your views. Else, {% csrf_token %} will be empty.

Comment: How would I use the context_instance? render(request, 'index.html', [what goes here?])

Comment: Oh, context_instance is for render_to_response. It is automatic with render (notice that render takes the request as argument, which allows context_processors to run). Did it do the trick ?

Comment: I still get the same error message. The return statement is now: return render(request, 'index.html') and I've also tried with my previous context: return render(request, 'index.html', {'state':state, 'username': username})

Comment: In `./manage shell`, do: `from django.conf import settings; 'django.core.context_processors.csrf' in settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. If that doesn't return True, then you should add `'django.core.context_processors.csrf'` to your `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. I was kind of suprised that {% csrf_token %} didn't choke for not having 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' in the context.

Comment: I did that and it returned false, so I added TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.core.context_processors.csrf', ) to settings.py and it still returns the same error.

Comment: By adding the context processor this way, you disabled all others context processors ! Remove this setting, in shell print django.conf.settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, paste that in your settings, and add django.core.context_processors.csrf there.. It's funny because it always worked by default for me ... Anyway, forgive me I should directly have pointed you to [this documentation, How to enable CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it)

Comment: I tried that, but it seems that I needed 'settings.TEMPLATE.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS'. Anyway, it printed ('django.core.context_processors.request', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth') which I pasted to the settings.py and added 'django.core.context_processors.csrf' at the end. But it still gives the same error.

Comment: Printing that in the shell shows that the new setting has been applied, but still I get the same error.